# jQueryUI addClass containing box-shadow with duration

Tags: jquery-ui, fadein, addclass, css, duration

i'm using jQueryUI to add a CSS-class to different section-elements.
What i do is:

```
$("#section1, #section2, #section3").addClass("test", 5000);
```

CSS-Code looks like this:

```
.test{
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px #3bc87f;
}
```

I'm a bit confused about that.
I expect the box-shadow to be faded in with a duration of 5000 ms (just like a fadeIn animation).
But everything that happens is that within the 5000ms nothing is changed.
And after 5000ms the box-shadow is immediately there.

I also tried to use the .animate() function.
Same result here.

Are there any solutions or proposals?

Thanks

Comment: can u write, how did you use the .animate() ???